# Mapbox click listener on base map fails when layers are added

Tags: reactjs, mapbox

I have a map within my react project where I want to use a click listener on the base map to find the coordinates of the point clicked.  It has worked fine for a while now.

The problem is that I've added a few layers using clusters, some of which have click listeners, and now clicking *anywhere* on the map gives me the error "There is already a source with this ID."  I think I get why - there's a click, but not on any of the layers.

I can't find any information on how to make the base map a layer, and thereby get an id for it to pass to the click listener.  So my question is, how to I attach a click listener to the base map while still using layers that may also have click listeners, too.

Answer (score 0):

So that was a big pain!  What was happening was that I was passing a function down to the component that contained the click listener and that function changed the state of the parent component.  Given that this is react, it caused the child components to rerender and thus Mapbox to error that there was already a source with the same id because the source had never been removed.

The solution was to wrap the code that added the source and attendant layers as a component, then create a cleanup component that contained `removeSource` (see [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5440)) and run that on unmounting.  I'm using the new hooks api, so I'm running a `setLayers` function in the `useEffect` hook, then returning `cleanup` from `useEffect`, but I bet this sort of idea would work fine with `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`.